# ServiceStack Customize HTTP Responses ADD message and errorCode

Tags: c#, http, http-post, servicestack, httpresponse

I'm trying to Add a **custom message** with an HTTP error response for my web services. I expect something like:

> The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable. **Custom message: {ErrorCode: 2, Error: "No Username"}**

I tried this:

```
throw new HttpError(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "No Username");
```

And this:

```
string ErrorMessage = "ErrorCode = 2, Error = No Username";
throw new HttpError(406, ErrorMessage);
```

And this:

```
var responseDto = new UserCreatedResponse { ErrorCode = 2, Error = "No Username" };
                    return new HttpResult(responseDto, HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable)
                    {
                        StatusDescription = "Computer says no",
                    };
```

I followed the serviceStack doc https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Customize-HTTP-Responses but I can't get it right, I get only the Http error "The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable." but not the custom message.
Have I misunderstood something? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example was right, e.g. here's the Test implementation for [CustomHttpErrorService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Test/blob/master/src/Test/Test.ServiceInterface/CustomHttpErrorService.cs)

```
public class CustomHttpError
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string StatusDescription { get; set; }
}

public class CustomHttpErrorResponse
{
    public string Custom { get; set; }
    public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}

public class CustomHttpErrorService : Service
{
    public object Any(CustomHttpError request)
    {
        throw new HttpError(request.StatusCode, request.StatusDescription);
    }
}
```

Which you can test from the deployed site at http://test.servicestack.net

- [/CustomHttpError?StatusCode=406&StatusDescription=CustomDescription](http://test.servicestack.net/json/reply/CustomHttpError?StatusCode=406&StatusDescription=CustomDescription)

Which does return the expected Response Status Code and Description:

```
HTTP/1.1 406 CustomDescription
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4.00 Win32NT/.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 05 Dec 2014 22:41:23 GMT
Content-Length: 449
```

This works in IIS, IIS Express as well as all ServiceStack Self Hosts. But unfortunately VS.NET Web Development Server doesn't support setting a Custom Status Description.

Comment: Hi @mythz, I'm trying to workout how to use your service and I'm sorry but I don't see the point to send errors information to receive... errors information. Please tell me if I missed the point. What I was thinking was and error handler that will analyse posted data and send back a different description for each kind of errors. I put my code on GitHub, witch you can see that I try to send back the same HTTP code and a different description for each error case. There is the link: https://github.com/SuperBulot/Custom_response/commit/c87c56868df516129d9b3fc586cd56ce89ec2c85
Thanks for your help

Comment: @Ben The above service is showing that throwing a `HttpError` in a Service does work as expected in self-hosting and most ASP.NET Web Servers, but wont work in VS WebDev server as it doesn't allow setting a custom StatusDescription.

Comment: I know, I'm using an ASP.NET Web server uder IIS 8.1. I guess I will just add my ErrorCode and error description in a classic DTOs Response. Thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

i dont know if i am going to answer you correctly

you could try something like this

throw new HttpError.   (After the dot it will show you a couple errors)

e.g

HttpError.NotFound("Place Custom Message in Here")

HttpError.Conflict("Place Custom Message in Here")

Comment: Hi Tanaka, your solution is not working, I can't implement it. Thanks anyway